# Using the matching class of isAssignableFrom() method in Java

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called `Pet` with lots of classes subclassing it.

```
public abstract class Animal {
}

public abstract class WildAnimal extends Animal {
}

public abstract class Pet extends Animal {
    public abstract void myNameIs();
}

public class Dog extends Pet {
    @Override
    public void myNameIs() {
        System.out.println("Dog Meat");
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Pet {
    @Override
    public void myNameIs() {
        System.out.println("Cheshire");
    }

    public void purr() {
        System.out.println("purr");
    }
}




// Somewhere else in my project ...

List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
// Lots of animals are added to this by:

animalMoves(animals);

public void petMoves(List<Animal> animals) {
if (Pet.class.isAssignableFrom(animals.getClass())) {
    // Could be a dog, cat, mouse, etc.
    Pet something = (Pet)pet;
```

I want to be able to call the overridden `myNameIs()` method for each subclassed class, not the abstract class' `myNameIs()`. How would I do so?

Comment: Just call `pet.myNameIs()`.  It will call the right method automatically.

Comment: By **definition**, you cannot call an abstract method (it has nothing to call).

Comment: Thanks, I tried calling animal.myNameIs() and it worked. I might have missed something before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `isAssignableFrom` check: your parameter is declared to have type `Pet`. Obviously, class `Pet` is assignable from anything that has type `Pet`, so, your check will always return true.

To answer your question: `pet.myNameIs()` will do what you you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized something. Will fix my question. Pet also is a subclass of an animal.

Comment: Doesn't matter whose subclass it is. Everything is a subclass of `Object` after all.